# mustache loading view dynamically

Tags: php, mustache

I'm trying to make a template with mustache.

```
layout.mustache
-- view/page1.mustache
-- view/page2.mustache
-- view/page3.mustache
```

I set my loader as layout.mustache and my partials as view directory.

Until this it's ok.

Based on the followed hierarchy I'm trying to load a view in my main layout with something like

```
$m->render('layout', array('page' => 'page1'));
```

and in my layout `{{> page}}` it's not working. It's returning "page1" it's not loading the mustache file...

I'm a new user in lesslogic template so I need your help... Maybe what i'm trying to do its not possible.

Thanks your for your future help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Mustache supported such a thing, it would look like `{{> {{page}} }}`, because what you're saying is not "load the page template", but "load the template named (value of page variable)". That's very much on the "logic" side of the line, so it's not something Mustache supports.

That said, you can do what you want to do, you just have to get a little creative :)

You can hijack Mustache's partials loader with something like [the filesystem alias loader here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878970/php-mustache-2-1-partial-loading-not-based-on-the-filename/14900573#14900573).

Then you'd instantiate Mustache with that as a partials loader:

```
$m = new Mustache_Engine(array(
    'partials_loader' => FilesystemAliasLoader('path/to/views')
));
```

Now, just before you render, you would set an alias for the `page` partial:

```
$m->getPartialsLoader()->setTemplate('page', 'page1');
$m->render('layout', $data);
```

When Mustache gets to your `{{> page }}` partial, it asks the FilesystemAliasLoader to load up "page". It looks up "page" in its aliases, and decides you meant "page1", and loads `view/page1.mustache` instead.