# Can I use a Mustache var in a partial name?

Tags: mustache, mustache.php

I currently use a template for multiple pages *(basic.mustache)* and everything work great, but I want to add different boxes *(box1.mustache, box2.mustache)* in a sidebar depending of the page.

Basically, I would need to add the mustache templates in the object parsed by the template.

```
{
  title: "My page tile",
  content: ...
  sidebar: [
    "box1.mustache",
    "box2.mustache"
  ]
}
```

but how can I do something equivalent to this in the main template *(basic.mustache)* ?

```
{{#sidebar}}
  {{>.}}
{{/sidebar}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to do like that. But it's still possible to accomplish what you're looking for. [See this answer for one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878970/php-mustache-2-1-partial-loading-not-based-on-the-filename/14900573#14900573).

Looking at your example, though, I think what you're looking for is better addressed by template inheritance (the [BLOCKS pragma](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/wiki/BLOCKS-pragma)).

So you'd have `layout.mustache` as your "parent" template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{$ title }}My site has a title!{{/ title }}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="main">
      {{$ content }}{{/ content }}
    </section>
    <section id="sidebar">
      {{$ sidebar }}{{/ sidebar }}
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

And `my_page.mustache` as your "page" template:

```
{{< layout }}

  {{$ title }}This page has its own title!{{/ title }}

  {{$ sidebar }}
    {{> box1 }}
    {{> box2 }}
  {{/ sidebar }}

  {{$ content }}
    Here's all your awesome content!
  {{/ content }}

{{/ layout }}
```

Notice how `my_page` loads `box1` and `box2` partials into the `{{$ sidebar }}` block. You could even have default sidebar partials by adding them to the `{{$ sidebar }}` block in the main layout (just like there's a default `{{$ title }}`).

*Note that BLOCKS is a pragma, and as such is not enabled by default in Mustache.php.* To use it, you either have to add `{{% BLOCKS }}` to the first line of any template with blocks in it, or pass `['pragmas' => [Mustache_Engine::PRAGMA_BLOCKS]]` to the Mustache_Engine constructor to enable them globally.

Comment: I tried to use the block as you suggested, but something is not working yet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27446987/rendering-mustache-block-with-external-templates

Comment: How can you use partial in the page template? 'partials_loader' seems incompatible with 'pragmas'

Comment: Ok, I realized I must keep the partials in the same folder as layout.mustache. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some Mustache implementations answer to this frequent question with support for "dynamic partials". See https://github.com/thelucid/tache (Ruby) and https://github.com/groue/GRMustache/blob/master/Guides/rendering_objects.md#example-dynamic-partials (Objective-C).

Answer (score 0):

If you build the string ahead like so

```
... part: "{{>" + MyPartialName + "}}"
```

then use in your template like so

```
{{>part}}
```

It appears to work. I haven't tested this in the original JS implementation yet (using .net), so some confirmation would be nice.