# Rendering Mustache Block with external templates

Tags: mustache, mustache.php

I'm using **Mustache 2.7.0** and trying to play with **Blocks pragma** for the first time.

Basically, I call *basic.mustache*

```
{{< layout }}
{{$ title}}{{page.meta.name}}{{/ title}}
{{/ layout }}
```

calling the block *layout.mustache*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <h1>{{$ title}}test{{/ title}}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I see the value of *page.meta.name* appear on the page, but not the tags written in *layout.mustache*.
Anyone have an idea why?

**PHP**

```
$mustache = new Mustache_Engine(array(
    'pragmas' => [Mustache_Engine::PRAGMA_BLOCKS],
    'loader' => new Mustache_Loader_FilesystemLoader('htdocs/templates'),
    'partials_loader' => new Mustache_Loader_FilesystemLoader('htdocs/templates/partials/')
));

$tpl = $mustache->loadTemplate('basic');
echo $tpl->render( $this );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that `partials_loader` are **not compatibles** with `Pragma blocks`.
Removing this line:

```
'partials_loader' => new Mustache_Loader_FilesystemLoader('htdocs/templates/partials/')
```

Solved my problem.

Comment: I think you realized this in your other question, but the issue is that parent templates are still considered partials, so they're loaded via the partials loader instead of the normal template loader. Most of the time, you should just use one template loader (and one directory) for both :)

Comment: Thanks. Saved me time and effort.