# How to dynamically load partials in Mustache PHP?

Tags: php, mustache, mustache.php

I'm having trouble finding decent docs on loading partials programmatically through Mustache.

I'm trying to load a login page with the form being a partial (it'll change depending on different user interactions).

PHP:

```
$m = new Mustache_Engine(array(
    'loader' => new Mustache_Loader_FilesystemLoader(dirname(__FILE__) . '/views'),
    'partials_loader' => new Mustache_Loader_FilesystemLoader(dirname(__FILE__) . '/views/login/partials')
));
$params = array();
$partials = array(
    'login_area' => 'login_form'
);
echo $m->render('login/login', $params, $partials);
```

Mustache:

```
<div id="login-area">
    {{> login_area}}
</div>
```

As I understand it, the `$partials` array should load my partial correctly.

However, I get no errors and nothing is displayed under `{{> login_area}}`

Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: Ok, so looking at the `render` function, it only accepts 2 arguments, so this isn't the correct method. Not that I know what is, yet...

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Mustache 2.1 partial loading NOT based on the filename](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878970/php-mustache-2-1-partial-loading-not-based-on-the-filename)