# Mustache Php: partials constructor not working

Tags: mustache.php

I am attempting to load a temple and within that template is a partial(nested template). Shouldn't the partials constructor render the `content` partial? Is the logic done wrong? 
Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30036447/how-to-dynamically-load-partials-in-mustache-php) but the implementation is different and no answer. The question appeared to die or was directed to somewhat similar question, but mine is also different in implementation.

base.mustache:

```
<body>  
{{>content}}
</body>
```

Mustache constructor:

```
if(!isset($this->mustache)){
            $options = array(
              'loader'=> new Mustache_Loader_FilesystemLoader('path/to/templates/'),
              'partials_loader' => new Mustache_Loader_FilesystemLoader('path/to/partials'),
              'partials' => array(
                  'content'=> $this->module->tplFile
              )
            );
            $this->mustache = new Mustache_Engine($options);
        }
```

Render template:

```
public function display()
    {
      $this->mustache->render('base.mustache');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you didn't even loaded the template.

Just edit your render template part like this :

```
public function display(){
  $this->mustache->loadTemplate('base')->render();
}
```

*Why just 'base' not 'base.mustache'*, you might ask.

Well, Mustache default loading a `.mustache` file so if you using `$this->mustache->loadTemplate('foo')`, it will automatically load a `foo.mustache` file under the path you set for file loader.

For more information, you could check in [Template Loading](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/wiki/Template-Loading) section from mustache.php's official wiki.

*Btw, my English sucks, so hope you understand what I saying.*