# PHP Mustache combine alias loader with regular partials

Tags: mustache.php

I'm using the Mustache alias loader from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878970/php-mustache-2-1-partial-loading-not-based-on-the-filename/14900573#14900573) to dynamically load partials (based on URL variables) into my default template.

This works like a charm, however, in some cases I would also like to load "regular" partials. Is there a way to combine both the dynamic alias loader and the regular partial loading?

Answer (score 1):

Yep! You can use the [Cascading Loader](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/wiki/Template-Loading#cascading-loader) to load both alias and regular partials. Something like this should do the trick:

```
$partials = [
  'sidebar' => 'themes/custom/sidebar',
];

$loader = new Mustache_Loader_CascadingLoader([
  new FilesystemAliasLoader('path/to/partials', $partials),
  new Mustache_Loader_FilesystemLoader('path/to/partials'),
]);
```

Comment: Cheers! Works like a charm :-)